# Parameter not recognized by Spring Data ElasticsearchCrudRepository

Tags: elasticsearch, spring-data

I have a @Document "Project" class with the following variables:

```
    @Document(indexName = "project-index")
    public class Project {
    ...
        @JsonProperty("import_id")
        private Long importId;

        private String title;
   ...
    //getters and setters
    }
```

My JSON is like the following

```
    {
       "_id" : ObjectId("5269fd92e4b0c74e42976c91"),
    ...
        "import_id" : NumberLong(1),
         "title" : "Something",
    ...
    }
```

And my @Repository class is like:

```
    @Repository
    public interface ProjectRepository extends ElasticsearchCrudRepository<Project, String>{
        Page<Project> findByImportId(Long importId, Pageable page);
        Page<Project> findByTitleLike(String title, Pageable page);
    }
```

The problem is that findByImportId is not getting any data, while findByTitleLike is working fine and letting me fetch data, I tried with different configurations, but seems that SpringData is not resolving that the field that has to search by import_id, even when it has @JsonProperty configured. Moreover, I tried to change the variable name to import_id (also the getter and setter) but in such case, when I tried to use findByImport_Id, findByImport_id, findByImport__Id or findByImport__id get an error at runtime.

Any idea how can I map a db variable with an underscore with a java variable that later could be recognized by ElasticsearchCrudRepository?

Thanks

Comment: I know this is an old post, but I am stuck with the same problem. Did you find any solution?

Answer (score 1):

from the [Spring Docs](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/data-commons/docs/current/reference/html/repositories.html):

> If your property names contain underscores (e.g. first_name) you can escape the underscore in the method name with a second underscore. For a first_name property the query method would have to be named findByFirst__name(…).

So it seems the correct would be findByImport__id

Comment: This isn't working for me as of spring-data-elasticsearch 1.2.0.RELEASE.